# "Format" CSV output in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, csv

Hi have a c++ program that generates a CSV file, all works fine but when I open the CSV file it looks rather messy and I have to manually expand columns to read all the text.

My question is, is there a way in Qt to do ay kind of formatting when generating CSV file e.g. make columns a certain width?

Comment: This is not a Qt issue. The CSV format itself does not offer any meta-information about column width or anything else. You could insert spaces to make them all the same width though.

Answer (score 0):

The QString class has several methods that you can use to format the fields of a CSV file.

As an example consider the `QString::leftJustified` method ([link to Qt docs here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#leftJustified)). Also, you may want to check the right equivalent.

The main advantage of using Qt APIs, in this case, is that you do not have to split formatting and arguments as with standard C++ APIs based on streams.

Anyhow the best API, among those of the QString class, depends on your specs. Check the Qt docs to learn more.